# blender normals not recalculating

Tags: normals

check out this file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r80hkvh4oulf4ra/faceOneWay.blend?dl=0

I'm trying to fix the normals to all go in one direction. I have tried recalculate and nothing is happening. Is there another way to make this work?

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Downvoted because the question is very broad or has no mean without the link which is not the way you should link a file here. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ because your dropbox link may be 404 (no more available) in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are a lot of faces that seem adjacent but are actually ripped, Blender can't guess in what direction they are supposed to be flipped, so make an <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*, give it a *Merge Distance* value of 0.02 for example, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Outside*.

Comment: Thank You this worked!!!

Comment: moonboots, you're doing a lot here and thanks, though, do not promote broad questions please. Or take the time to explain more the base situation either editing the question or providing more information in your answer. The site is not to be one to one interactions but intend to provide information that serves all people. Thanks

Comment: @lemon, I understand your point, I may be wrong but I think it's more constructive for everybody to accept bad questions and short answers than to be too severe on questions and to give no answer at all, if the original poster wanted to know more I would have told him of course, each answer can't be a deep explanation of all the 3D concepts (what are normals, etc) imho, otherwise you dissuade every one to answer and people asking for question won't have any... plus keep in mind that sometimes it takes hours to find a solution, you need to find a balance between fun and serious

Comment: Hi and thank you all for the comments. I'm not sure how the question was bad, but I'm always open for improvement. I've been tweaking normals for years in other applications, and this solution was perfect, and works better than anything else that I've tried... thank you all for your responses!

Comment: @tiCreativeMedia  yes exactly, you can't give a deep explanation of what are normals each time people meet a problem with normals, it makes no sense, plus you may know more than me on this topic ah ah  ;))

Comment: @tiCreativeMedia While the question isn't strictly bad overall, the way it is written right right now makes it too localized. There are no images illustrating the problem, the explanation is lacking and anyone reading or searching for a similar problem would have a hard time finding it. This makes it unlikely to be useful for future users, which is the main goal of this site. If you could rephrase it to include a short description of the issue and a few images illustrating the problem that'd be great.